# Ruby output as input for system command

Tags: ruby, posix

I am trying download a ton of files via [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) (Google Cloud). You can pass a list of URLs to download:

> You can pass a list of URLs (one per line) to copy on stdin instead of as command line arguments by using the -I option. This allows you to use gsutil in a pipeline to upload or download files / objects as generated by a program, such as:
>
> `some_program | gsutil -m cp -I gs://my-bucket`

How can I do this from Ruby, from *within* the program I mean? I tried to output them but that doesn't seem to work.

```rb
urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3"]
`echo #{puts urls} | gsutil -m cp -I gs://my-bucket`
```

Any idea?

A potential workaround would be to save the URLs in a file and use `cat file | gsutil -m cp -I gs://my-bucket` but that feels like overkill.

Comment: try with something like `urls = <<HEREDOC
url1
url2
url3
HEREDOC` so you have a string with multiple lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try `echo '#{urls.join("\n")}'`
If you put `puts` it returns nil, rather than the string you want to return. The interpolation fails due to the same reason.

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction! I am missing quotes around my echo statement: `echo '#{urls.join('\n')}' | wc -l\`